# InvalidOperationException: Cannot read value of type 'Vector2' from composite 'UnityEngine.InputSystem.Composites.Vector2Composite'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been tinkering with the Unity input system (the one you install as a package), trying to create a simple movement script, but immediately ran into a problem. The way I did it was create an action of the Value type, then bound WASD to a 2D Composite and then created a Unity event calling on the "Movement" function inside the player script.

```
public void Movement (InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    Debug.Log("!!!!!!");
    Vector2 moveVal = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    playerContainer.transform.Translate(new Vector3(moveVal.X, moveVal.Y, 0) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Anyway, up to this point it all works fine: the function is called on, and the button presses are registered, but any time I press them, it throws two exceptions. "InvalidOperationException: Cannot read value of type 'Vector2' from composite 'UnityEngine.InputSystem.Composites.Vector2Composite'" and "InvalidOperationException while executing 'performed' callbacks".

The problem seems to be this line:

```
Vector2 moveVal = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
```

but thing is, every single tutorial and solution out there uses the same piece of code, so it should work fine, I guess? What could be causing the problem on my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disclaimer, this is not an answer but I needed to include the picture/code]

Everything looks OK so I guess the error is in the Input Actions control. Compared to this example, do you see any differences?

[image]

To use the Input Actions above I use code like this:

```
public class PlayWithCube : MonoBehaviour
{
    NewControls newControls;

    private void Awake()
    {
        newControls = new NewControls();
        newControls.Game.Movement.performed += Movement_performed;
    }

    private void Movement_performed(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        var v = obj.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Debug.Log(v);
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        newControls.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    { 
        newControls.Disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out the problem was, since I called on the Movement function from the Unity Events in the Player Input component, I didn't actually declare the Controls in the beggining of the script, nor on awake, and that, for some reason, made ReadValue code behave differently. Problem solved. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason for not being able to read input as Vector2 was that **I accidentally used System.Numerics.Vector2 instead of UnityEngine.Vector2**.

Comment: If this is not related to the question please don´t post it as an answer. Answer fields should only be used to answer the question asked.

Comment: Although your answer could have been useful in some cases. It could be smart for next time to ask, through a comment on the question, for the namespaces used. This way you can determine if your answer would fit the question.